# In Rails, can I check in a view whether the action is to be cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using caches_page in controllers, like so:
caches_page :index

Is there a way I can check in the view files whether the action is to be cached or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All the `caches_page`-method does is to register a block via `after_filter` without storing any additional information. If you need to know wether the current action is to be cached, you will have to provide a clue yourself by ie. an enhanced version of `caches_page`.

Comment: Thank, Flitzwald. That is what I thought.